# Streaming a Growing Log File To Browser (DRF/Angular)

Tags: angularjs, django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework/AngularJs for developing a web application.

I have a use case in which server needs to stream the contents of a file in realtime, the file itself is growing since some other application is logging in to it. I know many inefficient ways to do this.

Can you suggest some better ways to achieve this. The Django "view" function should not return till the file is growing but still be able to send the incremental data to the client.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#streaminghttpresponse-objects

Comment: I am going through above link, looks like I need something similar. Thanks !